# running saas Compiler and checking whether the styles are applied are not

Tags: css, sass

Okay I have these 2 files style.css (under contents) and style.scss (under saas ). I will apply all changes that are made in style.css file to style.scss. So my question is whether i can compile my project using scss styles rather than style.css file.

Suppose i have  this in style.css

```
input[type='text'].rate-field
{
    border: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 0 0 6px;
}

input[type='text'].small-number
{
    width: 16px;
}

input[type='text'].watermark
{
    color: #ddd;
}

input[type='text'].datepicker
{
    width: 80px;
}
```

and this in style.scss

```
input[type='text'] {
  &.rate-field {
    border: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 0 0 6px;
  }
  &.small-number {
    width: 16px;
  }
  &.watermark {
    color: #ddd;
  }
  &.datepicker {
    width: 80px;
  }
}
```

Now is it possible that i will get the same desired style on my page if i COMMENTED ALL THE STYLES in style.css and compile using scss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea with SASS is you write a file named (for example) style.scss.

Then you compile that file (using a pre-processor such as PrePos) into the output file style.css.

You then upload this file to your web server.

You will never need to change the file style.css, any edits you make will be to style.scss which is then compiled.

Initially, when you're converting from .css to .scss I'd make a backup copy of your original CSS for reference, then, compile to SCSS and check that the site looks the same, thus proving that your SASS is correct.